# How to check and set empty fields present in an array with a value present in variable using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have an array `$_FILES['userFiles']['name']` which contains recently uploaded images names. All I want is to check the null fields present in an array i.e., 
`['userFiles']['name']==""` and update with value present in an array variable `$userFilesdata` in place of null value. If `$_FILES['userFiles']['name']` is only null if any value present it should not updated. Any help would be appropriated.

My code is :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($userFilesdata);$i++)
{

    if(($_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i])!="")  {   //If image is uploaded
    $_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i]=$userFilesdata[$i];
    }
    else{
    //Do some work
    }
    print_r($_FILES['userFiles']['name']);

}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at `isset()` and `is_null()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if(($_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i])!="")` with `if($_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i])`

Comment: i.e., ['userFiles']['name']=="" and update with value present in an array variable $userFilesdata in place of null value.  You already have mentioned it but you haven't implemented thin in the code :)